Subtraction of inverse points in secp256k1
In pure math given:
k = 10
l = -10
k + l = 0
k - l = 20

Now in secp256k1
$K = k*G$
$L = l*G$
$K+L = O$
$K-L = O$
Why do we get identity point on subtraction since:
$K-L = 10*G - (-10)*G = (10-(-10))*G = 20*G$

$P - P  = \mathcal{O}$ however $ P - ( -P) = [2]P$

I have been on this for several hours and I keep getting the same result. Maybe i should try a different secp256k1 library

Who knows, maybe you are misusing it, or your data is not what you thought.
